# Trouble Understanding a Checksum Algorithm

Tags: math, binary, checksum, crc

#### Protocol for BM62 Bluetooth Module

[image]

I just have a simple question about how the Checksum algorithm works for a particular Bluetooth module (BM62). The picture above has the UART protocol explained, and it explains the checksum rule, but I am having trouble understanding how it actually works, and cannot seem to guess the checksum value as it is given in the example in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea seems to be that you need to come up with `CHKSUM` such that `LENH` + `LENL` + `OPCODE` + `PARAM` + `CHKSUM` has 0 in the least significant byte. So, let's do the summation in 8 bits (or modulo 256):

`LENH` + `LENL` + `OPCODE` + `PARAM` + `CHKSUM` = 0

`CHKSUM` = -(`LENH` + `LENL` + `OPCODE` + `PARAM`)

IOW, `CHKSUM` = -(0 + 2 + 1 + 0) = -3 = 0xFD. (Remember that all of this was done in 8 bits).

You can verify that `CHKSUM` satisfies the requirement (you're now doing everything in 16 bits):

0 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 0xFD = 0x100

And that has 0 in the least significant byte. If we did this in 8 bits as well, we'd get 0 instead of 0x100 and that would also be a valid way to check correctness.